# Chrome says: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file which is styled using an XSL file. When opening the XML file in Firefox, I get no problems, (although strangely, sometimes it will only display after I hit "reload"), but in Chrome/Chromium I get the error message:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/xml
```

The files are up here: http://jonreeve.com/test/mike/biblexml.xml

I don't think there's anything irregular about the XML/XSL syntax, and the links all seem to be worded correctly, too.

Furthermore, this doesn't seem to be similar to all the similar-looking questions here, which seem to be dealing with javascript and other applications. This one is just pure XML/XSL.

Answer (score 9):

The **XSLT 1.0** spec clearly states that the appropriate MIME type for XSLT is
**text/xml** and **application/xml**

> [The MIME media types text/xml and application/xml [RFC2376] should be used for XSLT stylesheets. It is possible that a media type will be registered specifically for XSLT stylesheets; if and when it is, that media type may also be used.](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Introduction)

In **[XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xslt-media-type)** this was changed to **application/xslt+xml**.

But

> [In the absence of a registered media type for XSLT stylesheets, some vendors' products have adopted different conventions, notably type="**text/xsl**".](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#embedded)

Chrome 32.0.1700.107 returns errors:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type **text/xml**;
>
> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type **application/xml**;
>
> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type **application/xslt+xml**;

Chrome returns no error if **text/xsl** type passed.

Comment: There is an open Chrome issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=447866 for it. Voting it will uprise its priority.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT should be delivered with MIME type `application/xslt+xml`, not `application/xml`. You should configure your server to do so. You need a `.htaccess` file that contains the line

```
AddType application/xslt+xml .xsl
```

This associates the extension `.xsl` with the correct MIME type. If you already have a `.htaccess` file in the XSLT's directory or in a parent directory, you can add the line. Otherwise, create such a file.

Comment: Adding an .htaccess file gives me a "Forbidden" message with the note "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." I tried making the files executable, but this has no effect.