# Chrome 39 XML/XSLT Renders Blank Page

Tags: xml, google-chrome, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have old code from 2011 that has always worked properly. That is until Chrome 39. After beating my head in for awhile to try to diagnose, I determined that it works fine in IE, Firefox, and Chrome <= version 38. As of Chrome version 39, just a blank page is shown.

Seems like there is a change in handling of xsl/xslt, or xml, that is not allowing the page to render properly.

Are there any known changes to Chrome that would cause this? Any fix or workaround?

Thanks!

Example:

http://redemption.armory DOT eternal-wow.com SLASH arena-ladder.xml?ts=2&b=Eternal-WoW%21
http://eternal-wow.com

Comment: Your first link is a 404 error - also you should post code snippets here to help others assist you rather than just relying on links. See this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's not a 404. Works fine. There's too much code to paste since I've have no idea where the issue lies.

Comment: Nope - not for me, it 302's to http://redemption.armory.eternal-wow.com/login.xml?ref=character-select.xml which is a 404 error

Comment: Behviour same as i descibe when tesing with: http://web-sniffer.net/

Comment: You're just getting confused by the login redirect. I removed the first link so you don't keep trying that. Use the remaining link that doesn't require a login.

Comment: That 404 is not part of the problem you're describing. a 404 error is not browser specific

Comment: Read above. Also there is no 404.

Connect to 141.101.123.10 on port 80 ... ok

GET /arena-ladder.xml?ts=2&b=Eternal-WoW%21 HTTP/1.1
Host: redemption.armory.eternal-wow.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)
Accept-Encoding: gzip[CRLF]
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3
Referer: http://web-sniffer.net/

HTTP R        Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: There was a 404 on the link you just removed from your original post by editing it before making the claim it doesnt exist...

Comment: There was a 302 redirect on the first link, exactly like you said earlier before you changed your story. Do you wish to actually help now?

Comment: the 302 was a redirect to a 404...

Comment: Believe it or not I really am TRYING to help you (or at least trying to assist you find the help you need). Your first post popped up out of the review q. I tried to add comments that I thought would help you find the assistance you needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link works in Firefox but results in blank page in Chrome. I checked with webdev tools and noticed that Chrome loads the xsl files from a different url as Firefox, e.g. `.._layout/arena/language.xsl` (404) instead of `../_layout/language.xsl` (ok). In addition in Chrome I get the error message "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/xslt+xml: "http://redemption.armory.eternal-wow.com/_layout/arena/ladder.xsl".
 For this issue check [Chrome says: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752836/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-a)

The main problem seems to be the misinterpred `xsl:import` and `xsl:include` statements which seems to be a Chrome/Webkit Bug - see e.g. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8441 or google for "xsl import relative path chrome". The first import in `ladder.xsl` works: `<xsl:import href="../includes.xsl" />` (is loaded from `../_layout/includes.xsl`). The `<xsl:import href="language.xsl"/>` in the `includes.xsl` fails in Chrome - it's resolved to `../_layout/arena/language.xsl` instead of `../_layout/language.xsl`. Same applies to the `xsl:includes`, e.g. in the language.xsl - . `<xsl:include href="nav/menu.xsl" />` tries to include from `../_layout/arena/nav/menu.xsl` instead of `../_layout/nav/menu.xsl`.
 As it seems to be a Chrome Bug, you could either try to just copy the xsl files to the location where Chrome is looking for them or try to adjust the include/import paths as Chrome seems to interpret the locations based on the main template - as `"../includes.xsl"` is working as import from the `ladder.xsl` in the arena-directory but `<xsl:import href="language.xsl"/>` in the `includes.xsl` is not resolved relative to the `language.xsl`, but instead relative to the `ladder.xsl`, changing to `<xsl:import href="../language.xsl"/>` might work for Chrome (but maybe won't work for other browsers, so I won't recommend that). Two suggestions - either you double the imports/includes, keeping the current imports/includes and adding each of them with a path relative to the `ladder.xsl`, or, which would be a cleaner solution, you check if you can move all imports and includes to the ladder.xsl and adjust the paths accordingly.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I at first tried symlinks to fix the issue, but that didn't work. So I changed all the included files to absolute paths instead of relative paths, and that fixes the issue.  It's kind of a dirty fix, and it will require hundreds of changes to affect the whole site. I'm sure there's a better approach, maybe using .htaccess or something, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Nevermind, it kind of breaks it for the other browsers. That doesn't work at all.

Comment: I tried the symlink thing again, and had missed some before. It actually works if I get every link. It's just very messy and drives me crazy.

Comment: @Derek Though it's also a kind of a dirty fix - just keeping the xsls at the current location where it's working for non-webkit browers and copying them to the location where Chrome is trying to load is not an option? Just cause that shouldn't require so many changes. But if the symlink approach works it's of course the better solution as it's cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm going to go with this symlink method for now. It's much better than duplicate files. I've marked yours as the answer, but if anyone knows a better way or a fix, please let me know.